# Change the order of menus in sitemap page for visitors view

Tags: 7

I have installed [Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map) module and enable some menus to display for HTML sitemap page.

Now I need to change the order of titles (Menu) that are displaying on sitemap page.

Is there any way we can change the order of these menus?